# SQL - How can I get the number of duplicates in the non-aggregated result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

Suppose I have a table `tb` such that

```
select * from tb
```

returns

```
ID | City     | Country
1  | New York | US     
2  | Chicago  | US     
3  | Boston   | US     
4  | Beijing  | China  
5  | Shanghai | China  
6  | London   | UK
```

What is the easiest way to write a query that can return the following result?

```
ID | City     | Country | Count
1  | New York | US      | 3
2  | Chicago  | US      | 3
3  | Boston   | US      | 3
4  | Beijing  | China   | 2
5  | Shanghai | China   | 2
6  | London   | UK      | 1
```

The only solution I can think of is

```
with cte as (select country, count(1) as Count from tb group by country)
select tb.*, cte.Count from tb join cte on tb.Country = cte.Country
```

But I feel that is not succinct enough. I am wondering if there is anything like `Duplicate_Number() over (partition by country)` to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
      ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Country)
from tb
```

The [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the
>   associated window function is applied.

So, we are basically telling to `COUNT` the records, but to group the rows per `COUNTRY`.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew aggregation functions can be used together with the over clause. This opens up a big new world for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to achieve the result :

```
select t1.*, t2.Country_Count from tb t1
join 
    (select country, count(country) Country_Count from tb group by country) t2
on t1.country=t2.country
order by t1.id
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ea05c/5)